# How to show both of my buttons on same line?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

[image]
I'll post both entire form elements even though it might not all be needed to answer the question.

Both buttons are at very end of this code snippet.

I haven't been able to successfully add any row divs, etc. since a form is ending in the middle of the div, and another beginning, it doesn't seem to work.
Any advice?

Thank you.

```
<div class="row content-section col-md-10">
            <form method="POST" action="">
                {{ form.csrf_token() }}
                    
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">
                        {% if sales_order_number %}
                            <h3>Sales Order Number: {{ sales_order_number }}</h3>
                        {% else %}
                            <h3>?? No Sales Order Number ??</h3>
                        {% endif %}

                        {% if total_controllers_configured %}
                            <h3>Total Controllers Configured for this job: {{ total_controllers_configured }} / {{ sales_order_controller_quantity }} </h3>
                        {% else %}
                            <h3> Total Controllers Configured for this job: 0 / {{ sales_order_controller_quantity }} </h3>
                        {% endif %} 
                        <br>
                        Configure Controller {{ current_controller }} Below:
                    </legend>

                    <!-- Fan Quantity and Modbus Ranges -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                            {{ form.modbus_ranges.label(class="form-control-label") }}

                            {% if form.modbus_ranges.errors %}
                                {{ form.modbus_ranges(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    {% for error in form.modbus_ranges.errors %}
                                        <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            {% else %}
                                {{ form.modbus_ranges(class="form-control form-control-lg", id="modbus-ranges") }}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    
                            {{ form.fan_quantity.label(class="form-control-label") }}

                            {% if form.fan_quantity.errors %}
                                {{ form.fan_quantity(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    {% for error in form.fan_quantity.errors %}
                                        <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            {% else %}
                                {{ form.fan_quantity(class="form-control form-control-lg" , id="fan-quantity") }}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- fan type, controller type, serial number -->
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            {{ form.controller_type.label(class="form-control-label") }}

                            {% if form.controller_type.errors %}
                                {{ form.controller_type(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    {% for error in form.controller_type.errors %}
                                        <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            {% else %}
                                {{ form.controller_type(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            {{ form.controller_serial_number.label(class="form-control-label") }}

                            {% if form.controller_serial_number.errors %}
                                {{ form.controller_serial_number(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    {% for error in form.controller_serial_number.errors %}
                                        <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            {% else %}
                                {{ form.controller_serial_number(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-check">
                        {{ form.gfa_fire_NC(class="form-check-input") }}
                        {{ form.gfa_fire_NC.label(class="form-check-label") }}
                    </div>
                <div class="form-group text-left col-md-6">
                    {{ form.save_configuration(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            </form>

            
            <form action="" method="POST" novalidate>
                {{ form.csrf_token() }}
                <div class="form-group text-right col-md-6">
                    <input type='submit' class="btn btn-outline-danger" name='clear_configuration' value="Clear Configuration"></input>
                    <!-- {{ form.clear_configuration(class="btn btn-outline-danger", required=False) }} -->
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Your link isn't working

Comment: @berkobienb thank you for pointing this out. I tried uploading directly into my question now, let me know if that worked. Thank you!